# How do I add a file/folder selector to a screen?

Tags: acumatica

I need a control that will allow me to select either a file or a folder (or both) from the user file system. Is there some kind of control that can be used in both existing screens and on new ones ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've combined both the file and folder selector in the same control but I think it will be easy enough for you to understand how to do either one.
I've made my example using an extension of SOOrderEntry, but it is the same principle for a new screen or another existing one.

In the PXDataSource element, add Datatrees and PXTreeDataMember elements as follow :

```xml
<px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%" TypeName="PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry" PrimaryView="Document">
        <DataTrees>
            <px:PXTreeDataMember TreeView="FilesTree" TreeKeys="FileKey" />
        </DataTrees>
</px:PXDataSource>
```

In the formView element, add the PXTreeSelector :

```xml
<px:PXFormView ID="PXFormView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" Width="100%" DataMember="Document" Caption="Order Summary"
    NoteIndicator="True" FilesIndicator="True" LinkIndicator="True" EmailingGraph="PX.Objects.CR.CREmailActivityMaint,PX.Objects"
    ActivityIndicator="True" ActivityField="NoteActivity" DefaultControlID="edOrderType" NotifyIndicator="True"
    TabIndex="14900">
    <Template>
        <px:PXTreeSelector runat="server" TreeDataSourceID="ds" TreeDataMember="FilesTree" InitialExpandLevel="0" MinDropWidth="413" PopulateOnDemand="True" ShowRootNode="False" AllowEditValue="True" SelectOnFocus="False" DataField="ParentFolder" ID="edPathSelector">
            <DataBindings>
                <px:PXTreeItemBinding DataMember="FilesTree" TextField="FileName" ValueField="FilePath" DescriptionField="FilePath" ImageUrlField="Icon" />
            </DataBindings>
        </px:PXTreeSelector>
    </Template>
</px:PXFormView>
```

Here is my DAC and graph extension. As you can see, the graph pretty much only calls the .NET function to enumerable files and folders. To specialize a control for either folder or files, you just need to return the right elements.

```cs
using PX.Data;
using PX.Web.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RowFilesTree : IBqlTable
    {
        [PXString(IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "FileKey")]
        public string FileKey { get; set; }
        public class fileKey : IBqlField { }


        [PXString]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Path")]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public class filePath : IBqlField { }


        [PXString]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Name")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public class fileName : IBqlField { }

        [PXString(250)]
        public virtual string Icon { get; set; }
        public abstract class icon : IBqlField {}
    }


    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public PXSelect<RowFilesTree> FilesTree;
        protected virtual IEnumerable filesTree([PXString]string FilePath)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath))
            {
                var folders = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    yield return new RowFilesTree()
                    {
                        FileKey = folder.Replace(':', '>'),
                        FileName = folder,
                        FilePath = folder,
                        Icon = Sprite.Tree.GetFullUrl(Sprite.Tree.Folder)
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var folders = new string[0];
                var files = new string[0];

                try
                {
                    var decode = FilePath.Replace('>', ':');
                    folders = Directory.GetDirectories(decode);
                    files = Directory.GetFiles(decode);

                }
                catch
                {
                }

                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    yield return new RowFilesTree()
                    {
                        FileKey = folder.Replace(':', '>'),
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(folder),
                        FilePath = folder,
                        Icon = Sprite.Tree.GetFullUrl(Sprite.Tree.Folder)
                    };
                }


                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    yield return new RowFilesTree()
                    {
                        FileKey = file.Replace(':', '>'),
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(file),
                        FilePath = file,
                        Icon = Sprite.Tree.GetFullUrl(Sprite.Tree.Leaf)
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the final result :

[image: Final result]